# Unused argument problem when launching /etc/ros/openni_head.launch on PR2 Hydro

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, openni-launch, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I tried to launch the OpenNI Kinect driver on PR2, I do:

```
roslaunch /etc/ros/openni_head.launch
```

And then I got the following error message:

```
unused args [name] for include of [/opt/ros/hydro/share/openni_launch/launch/includes/manager.launch]
```

Nothing was started.

[Here](http://notepad.cc/xiapiddu13) is the openni_head.launch file. I think that the problem is from line 47~50:

```
  <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/manager.launch">
    <arg name="name" value="$(arg manager)" />
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
  </include>
```

After I omitted the line "", I get another error:

```
[FATAL] [WallTime: 1381238959.313747] manager.launch has moved to rgbd_launch! Replace "$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/manager.launch" with "$(find rgbd_launch)/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml". This notice will be removed in ROS Indigo
[FATAL] [WallTime: 1381238959.424237] device.launch has moved to openni_launch! Replace "$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/device.launch" with "$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/device.launch.xml". This notice will be removed in ROS Indigo
[FATAL] [WallTime: 1381238959.470131] processing.launch has moved to rgbd_launch! Replace "$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/processing.launch" with "$(find rgbd_launch)/launch/includes/processing.launch.xml". This notice will be removed in ROS Indigo
================================================================================REQUIRED process [manager_deprecated-1] has died!
process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/pr2admin/.ros/log/29e33790-3011-11e3-9aea-001517ebc33d/manager_deprecated-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
```

Then I followed the instruction and replace "$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/manager.launch" with "$(find rgbd_launch)/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml".

Here's another error I got:

```
included file [/opt/ros/hydro/share/rgbd_launch/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml] requires the 'name' arg to be set
```

Okay...let's add it back again. And then I got another error:

```
included file [/opt/ros/hydro/share/rgbd_launch/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml] requires the 'num_worker_threads' arg to be set
```

Well...can anyone provide a workable launch file for running Kinect driver?

My PR2 is running on ROS Hydro. Thanks for any help~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88591/unused-argument-problem-when-launching-/etc/ros/openni_head.launch-on-pr2-hydro/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdorich](https://answers.ros.org/users/7496/jdorich/) on 2013-10-08**:
Is there a reason you are not using "openni_launch openni.launch" similar to here: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/hydro-devel/turtlebot_bringup/launch/3dsensor.launch

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-10-11**:
Good idea! I just tested the openni.launch in openni_launch package. There are some transform errors such that the PointCloud data can't be transformed to the base_link. After checking the doc website, I'll try to set some of the parameters to make the transform work. Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @jdorich. I've modified the launch file based on openni.launch in openni_launch package so that it can run on PR2 Hydro correctly.

In case that someone got the same problem, [here](http://notepad.cc/giozbaipa52) is the file.

The `<!--###MODIFIED###-->` comment means that the following line is where I comment out or add a new line.

---

Originally posted by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) with karma: 301 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [honky](https://answers.ros.org/users/15546/honky/) on 2014-05-10**:
Link is dead, could you please provide any hint for solving the issue? Would be real nice. Thx.

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-06-14**:
dead link, please send it in some link where nobody can change the info ;)